# Find string's first index l for sub-strings in the original string?

Tags: python

Find the first character's index for string in `num_series`.

I think there must be a trick answer, but I can not think out of it.

```
import re

original = '*111N12311NN123456**1222***12'
num_series = re.findall('1[2-9]+|[2-9]+|1',
                        '234**12311*111N12311NN123456**1222***12')
```

Expected_result = `[0, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 18, 19, 22, 30, 37]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.finditer` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.finditer)) instead of `re.findall`:

```
import re
print( [i.start() for i in re.finditer('1[2-9]+|[2-9]+|1', '234**12311*111N12311NN123456**1222***12')] )
```

Prints:

```
[0, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 18, 19, 22, 30, 37]
```